# How check column Exits or not in SQLITE in Phonegap

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

i want check field exits or not in Sqlite table. I searched and found PRAGMA is there but i didn't know how to use it in phonegap.

my problem is that i have one table,in that table a, b, c name field.
    Now i want to add d name field when table didn't contain d name field..if d name field exits no need to add that field.

So how is it possible in sqlite using phonegap???.

Comment: Using JavaScript to query an SQLite? How? Using Node.js?

Comment: You use the PRAGMA exactly like any other query.

Comment: Hello CL. can you give some good example of PRAGMA.i didnt know how to use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope most of them know about Phonegap Storage Feature. If you need more about [CLICK](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.9.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage)

Put this line of code out of all function just like **addEventListener** for **deviceready**

```
var db = window.openDatabase("DB_NAME", "DB_VERSION", "DB_DESCRIPTION", "DB_SIZE");
```

Because this will available all functions just like ***global variable***. Above code will return new database if there is no database found otherwise it will return old database object

```
// Code for call column exist function call     
db.transaction(findColumnExist, errorFunction, successFunction);
```

Here I put my all query callback functions

```
    function findColumnExist(tx) {
        tx.executeSql("select <COLUMN_FOR_CHECK> from <TABLE_NAME> LIMIT 1", [], querySuccess, queryFail);
    }

    function errorFunction(err) {
        console.log("Transaction failure => errorcb-->error msg "+err.message+" error code "+err.code);
    }
    function successFunction() {
        consol.log("success!");
    }

    function querySuccess(tx, results){
        console.log(results.rows.item(0));      
    }
    function queryFail(err){
         console.log("Query Failure => errorcb-->error msg "+err.message+" error code "+err.code);
        // IF queryFail reached column not found so again use executeSql() function for add new column
    }
```

Comment: welcome and thanks for valuable question to @Piyush, if got solution accept answer. so that others can uses the answer.